# Understanding the case in the start of טהרות ח:ח

Tags: maseches-taharos

I'm having trouble visualizing the scenario in טהרות פרק ח משנה ח and hope someone can explain it to me. Specifically, I'm looking at the start of the משנה, as explained by the קהתי, the יכין before him, and (I think) the רמב״ם before *him*.

Seemingly there's a kneading trough that has one part of its floor lower than the rest of its floor, and somehow three pieces of dough are touching water that's collected in the lower part, but only some of the water is touching each piece of dough. Or something. Can someone please explain it better, or, even better, draw it?

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to [mbloch](/users/11501/mbloch) who pointed me to the ArtScroll commentary. It clarifies that the water is not only in the lower part of the trough's floor, but all along the floor (which is on an incline). So you have an inclined surface, which is sopping wet, and sitting on it (on the water) are the balls of dough.